# How to evaluate the following integrals using Mathematica?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, special-functions

I have the following integrals obtained during solving heat diffusion equation for semi-infinite system that is subject to non-homogenous initial condition in Laplace domain. I want to simplify the solution by evaluating the following integrals. I have tried to obtain the solution using Mathematica but it outputs the integral without solution.

```
Integrate[
 x Exp[-\[Theta] x^2/(4 t)] (Sqrt[\[Theta]]/Sqrt[
    s ] (1/Sqrt[\[Theta] s ] - 
      rTD BesselK[0, 
        x Sqrt[s \[Theta]]] (BesselI[1, rTD Sqrt[s \[Theta]]] + 
         BesselI[0, Sqrt[s \[Theta]]]/
          BesselK[0, Sqrt[s \[Theta]]] BesselK[1, 
           rTD Sqrt[s \[Theta]]]))), {x, rTD, Infinity}]
```

```
Integrate[
 x Exp[-\[Theta] x^2/(4 t)] (Sqrt[\[Theta]]/Sqrt[
    s ] (rTD BesselK[1, 
       rTD Sqrt[s \[Theta]]] (BesselI[0, x Sqrt[s \[Theta]]] - 
        BesselK[0, x Sqrt[s \[Theta]]] BesselI[0, Sqrt[s \[Theta]]]/
         BesselK[0, Sqrt[s \[Theta]]]))), {x, 0, rTD}]
```

Comment: Numerically, evaluating parameters, e. g. `s = 1; \[Theta] = 1; t = 1; rTD = 1; NIntegrate[
 x Exp[-\[Theta] x^2/(4 t)] (Sqrt[\[Theta]]/
     Sqrt[s] (1/Sqrt[\[Theta] s] - 
      BesselK[0, 
        x Sqrt[s \[Theta]]] (BesselI[1, rTD Sqrt[s \[Theta]]] + 
         BesselI[0, Sqrt[s \[Theta]]]/
           BesselK[0, Sqrt[s \[Theta]]] BesselK[1, 
           rTD Sqrt[s \[Theta]]]))), {x, rTD, Infinity}]`. This results in `1.0048`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am interested in a solution of a mathematical form not numerical value because I am going to invert the solution from Laplace domain to the real domain.@user64494